# Why does boolean indexing return all NaNs

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, pandas

I have this CSV file `emp.csv`:

```
index   empno   ename   job mgr hiredate    sal comm    deptno
0,  7839,   KING,   PRESIDENT,  0,  1981-11-17,     5000,   0,  10
1,  7698,   BLAKE,  MANAGER,    7839,   1981-05-01, 2850,   0,  30
2,  7782,   CLARK,  MANAGER,    7839,   1981-05-09, 2450,   0,  10
3,  7566,   JONES,  MANAGER,    7839,   1981-04-01, 2975,   0,  20
4,  7654,   MARTIN, SALESMAN,   7698,   1981-09-10, 1250,   1400,   30
5,  7499,   ALLEN,  SALESMAN,   7698,   1981-02-11, 1600    300,    30
6,  7844,   TURNER, SALESMAN,   7698,   1981-08-21, 1500,   0,  30
7,  7900,   JAMES,  CLERK,      7698,   1981-12-11, 950,    0,  30
8,  7521,   WARD,   SALESMAN,   7698,   1981-02-23, 1250,   500,    30
9,  7902,   FORD,   ANALYST,    7566,   1981-12-11, 3000,   0,  20
10, 7369,   SMITH,  CLERK,      7902,   1980-12-09, 800,    0,  20
11, 7788,   SCOTT,  ANALYST,    7566    1982-12-22, 3000,   0,  20
12, 7876,   ADAMS,  CLERK,      7788,   1983-01-15, 1100,   0,  20
13, 7934,   MILLER, CLERK,      7782,   1982-01-11, 1300,   0,  10
```

Using the following code, I get all `NaN`'s:

```
import csv
import sys
import pandas as pd
import dateutil

# Load data from csv file
emp = pd.DataFrame.from_csv("D:\R data\emp.csv")
# Convert date from string to date times`enter code here`
emp['hiredate'] = emp['hiredate'].apply(dateutil.parser.parse, dayfirst=True)
jonessal = emp[['sal']][emp['ename']=='JONES']
empename = emp[['ename','sal']][emp['sal'] > jonessal] 
print(empename)
```

This is the output of the code:

```
index           
0       NaN  NaN
1       NaN  NaN
2       NaN  NaN
3       NaN  NaN
4       NaN  NaN
5       NaN  NaN
6       NaN  NaN
7       NaN  NaN
8       NaN  NaN
9       NaN  NaN
10      NaN  NaN
11      NaN  NaN
12      NaN  NaN
13      NaN  NaN
```

My desired output is:

```
index             
0       KING  5000
9       FORD  3000
11     SCOTT  3000
```

I thought that variable `jonesal`'s value is 2975, but the result is `NaN`.

It works correctly if I hardcode the salary with `empename = emp[['ename','sal']][emp['sal'] > 2975 ]`  but it returns all NaN's when I use a variable instead: `empename = emp[['ename','sal']][emp['sal'] > jonessal]`

Comment: Yu, use "{}"-shaped button after selection of your code to get correct formatting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`jonessal` is a DataFrame.

```
emp[['ename','sal']][emp['sal'] > jonessal]
```

Here, the comparison `emp['sal'] > jonessal` is not against a scalar, and due to brodcasting it returns a weird DataFrame. Since the indices/shapes don't match, your final result consists of NaNs.

Here, you make an assumption that there is only one employee called Jones. Following the same assumption, you can get the scalar with:

```
jonessal = emp.loc[emp['ename']=='JONES', 'sal'].values[0]
```

(`.values` return an array, and `[0]` comes from the single employee assumption.)

Now, it will return the same result:

```
emp[['ename','sal']][emp['sal'] > jonessal]
Out[81]: 
    ename   sal
0    KING  5000
9    FORD  3000
11  SCOTT  3000
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and [`ix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ix.html), which filter only columns `ename` and `sal`:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

temp=u"""index   empno   ename   job mgr hiredate    sal comm    deptno
0,  7839,   KING,   PRESIDENT,  0,  1981-11-17,     5000,   0,  10
1,  7698,   BLAKE,  MANAGER,    7839,   1981-05-01, 2850,   0,  30
2,  7782,   CLARK,  MANAGER,    7839,   1981-05-09, 2450,   0,  10
3,  7566,   JONES,  MANAGER,    7839,   1981-04-01, 2975,   0,  20
4,  7654,   MARTIN, SALESMAN,   7698,   1981-09-10, 1250,   1400,   30
5,  7499,   ALLEN,  SALESMAN,   7698,   1981-02-11, 1600,    300,    30
6,  7844,   TURNER, SALESMAN,   7698,   1981-08-21, 1500,   0,  30
7,  7900,   JAMES,  CLERK,      7698,   1981-12-11, 950,    0,  30
8,  7521,   WARD,   SALESMAN,   7698,   1981-02-23, 1250,   500,    30
9,  7902,   FORD,   ANALYST,    7566,   1981-12-11, 3000,   0,  20
10, 7369,   SMITH,  CLERK,      7902,   1980-12-09, 800,    0,  20
11, 7788,   SCOTT,  ANALYST,    7566,    1982-12-22, 3000,   0,  20
12, 7876,   ADAMS,  CLERK,      7788,   1983-01-15, 1100,   0,  20
13, 7934,   MILLER, CLERK,      7782,   1982-01-11, 1300,   0,  10"""
#after testing replace io.StringIO(temp) to filename
emp = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), 
                 skipinitialspace=True,
                 skiprows=1, 
                 parse_dates=[5], 
                 names=['index','empno','ename', 'job','mgr','hiredate','sal','comm','deptno'])
```

```
print (emp)
    index  empno   ename        job   mgr   hiredate   sal  comm  deptno
0       0   7839    KING  PRESIDENT     0 1981-11-17  5000     0      10
1       1   7698   BLAKE    MANAGER  7839 1981-05-01  2850     0      30
2       2   7782   CLARK    MANAGER  7839 1981-05-09  2450     0      10
3       3   7566   JONES    MANAGER  7839 1981-04-01  2975     0      20
4       4   7654  MARTIN   SALESMAN  7698 1981-09-10  1250  1400      30
5       5   7499   ALLEN   SALESMAN  7698 1981-02-11  1600   300      30
6       6   7844  TURNER   SALESMAN  7698 1981-08-21  1500     0      30
7       7   7900   JAMES      CLERK  7698 1981-12-11   950     0      30
8       8   7521    WARD   SALESMAN  7698 1981-02-23  1250   500      30
9       9   7902    FORD    ANALYST  7566 1981-12-11  3000     0      20
10     10   7369   SMITH      CLERK  7902 1980-12-09   800     0      20
11     11   7788   SCOTT    ANALYST  7566 1982-12-22  3000     0      20
12     12   7876   ADAMS      CLERK  7788 1983-01-15  1100     0      20
13     13   7934  MILLER      CLERK  7782 1982-01-11  1300     0      10

jonessal = emp.ix[emp['ename'] == 'JONES', 'sal'].iat[0]
print (jonessal)
2975
empename = emp.ix[emp['sal'] > jonessal, ['ename','sal']]
print (empename)
    ename   sal
0    KING  5000
9    FORD  3000
11  SCOTT  3000
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Below code's result  is also display NaN. 

jonessal = emp[['sal']][emp['ename']=='JONES'] 

empename = emp[['ename','sal']][emp['sal'] > jonessal]

print(empename)

Comment: OOPs, sorry. one possible solution describe `ayhan` in another answer, I add other solution with `iat` - select first value in `Series` with one value.

Answer (score 1):

You did incorrect call of `DataFrame.from_csv`. By default it expect comma "," as field separator:

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_csv.html

```
Parameters:
  sep : string, default ‘,’
Field delimiter
```

But you csv is not comma separated, but tab separated.

Try adding `sep='\t'` parameter to from_csv call: `pd.DataFrame.from_csv("D:\R data\emp.csv",sep='\t')`

Comment: thank you for  your answer. but emp.csv  using  this code is  comma separated.

Comment: yu, did you post the emp.csv file unchanged in your question? Here it looks like tab-separated - there are spaces and/or tab characters between columns. If it is really commas between, edit your question and add actual lines from `emp.csv` file (header and ten - twenty lines with data).

Comment: I edited my post. emp.csv file comma between columns. but display is NaN

Comment: Yu, it has not comma after first column: "0   7839,   KING, "

Comment: Yu, you may accept the answer which solved your problem (and please, give real input files in questions, I still can't understand are there commas in header line or not)